# Merging stack traces in rethrown errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, stack-trace, winston

I'm rethrowing here an error from Sequelize promise (Bluebird). In the first place, this was done to change error message, but as it appeared, this also produces more informative stack trace.

It is something like

```
sequelize.sync().catch(originalError => {
  const rethrownError = new Error(originalError.msg + ': ' + originalError.sql);
  throw rethrownError;
});
```

Where `originalError.stack` doesn't contain the line that caused the error but it holds important information that it originates in Sequelize and MySQL driver:

```
SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_KEY_COLUMN_DOES_NOT_EXITS: Key column 'NonExisting' doesn't exist in table
    at Query.formatError (...\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:175:14)
    at Query._callback (...\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:49:21)
    at Query.Sequence.end (...\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:85:24)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (...\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:94:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (...\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:280:23)
    at Parser.write (...\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:74:12)
    at Protocol.write (...\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (...\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:109:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:548:20)
```

`rethrownError.stack` contains the point of interest (the first line in the stack) but everything else is a rubbish:

```
Error: ER_KEY_COLUMN_DOES_NOT_EXITS: Key column 'NonExisting' doesn't exist in table
    at sequelize.sync.catch (...\app.js:59:17)
    at tryCatcher (...\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (...\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:504:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (...\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:561:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (...\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:606:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (...\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:681:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (...\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (...\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:148:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (...\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:637:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:610:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:582:5)
```

I would like to keep the information about both of them - and to designate the link between them, not just to add as two unrelated log entries.

I've been thinking on logging them as a single error with concatenated stack, `rethrownError.stack += '\n' + originalError.stack`.

How should these two errors be treated? Should their stack traces be joined? Is there a convention for merging error stacks in JavaScript (Node.js in particular)?

The intention is to keep the resulting error meaningful and to not upset existing tools that parse error stack traces (namely Stacktrace.js).

The projects under consideration use Winston logger or plain `console.error`, so the error is stringified at some point (in the example above it was logged via unhandled rejection handler).

Comment: As someone who's used sequelize a fair bit: why are you rethrowing at all? The moment you hit `catch()` you should be handling the error in a way that does not lead to further throws.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It is out of the scope of the question, but I originally did this to concat error `sql` prop to `msg`, I wasn't very happy to see in logs ER_KEY_COLUMN_DOES_NOT_EXITS that doesn't explain anything. But here I'm interested in the stack from rethrown error, `at sequelize.sync.catch...`. From original error, is not obvious at all where it has occured.

Comment: Preventing going down an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) rabbit hole is never out of scope. As for the error from your comment: that is an incredibly clear MySQL error that tells you that you're using a column name for a table that doesn't *have* that column name. Nothing worth rethrowing errors there, you should just log the table name you tried to use and the set of columns you users, so you can verify against a MySQL `show create table {tablename}`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**UPDATE 2022:** `Error.prototype.cause` has been implemented in [ES2022](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_exception-handling.html#error.cause). Consider using the native implementation.

> Since ECMAScript 2022, new Error() lets us specify what caused it:

```js
try {
  // ···
} catch (error) {
  throw new Error(
    `While processing ${filePath}`,
    {
      cause: error
    }
  );
}
```

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/cause

---

**Original answer:**

Here is a lightweight alternative to VError: [rerror](https://github.com/borisdiakur/rerror)
(I’m the author)

The idea is the same: Wrapping errors in errors. However it is much simpler. It has less features, but also works in the browser. It also takes into account that creating stack traces is expensive. Instead of creating stack traces and appending them to a string it creates a stack of errors internally and only creates the big stack trace if you need it (use the getter).

**Example**

```
function fail() {
  throw new RError({
    name: 'BAR',
    message: 'I messed up.'
  })
}

function failFurther() {
  try {
    fail()
  } catch (err) {
    throw new RError({
      name: 'FOO',
      message: 'Something went wrong.',
      cause: err
    })
  }
}

try {
  failFurther()
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err.why)
  console.error(err.stacks)
}
```

**Output**

```
FOO: Something went wrong. <- BAR: I messed up.
Error
    at failFurther (/Users/boris/Workspace/playground/es5/index.js:98:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/boris/Workspace/playground/es5/index.js:107:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:590:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
<- Error
    at fail (/Users/boris/Workspace/playground/es5/index.js:88:9)
    at failFurther (/Users/boris/Workspace/playground/es5/index.js:96:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/boris/Workspace/playground/es5/index.js:107:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:590:10)
```

A recommended read: https://www.joyent.com/node-js/production/design/errors

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, there is no built-in way to handle nested errors in Node.js. The only thing I can recommend you is to use the [VError library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/verror). It is really useful when dealing with advanced error handling.

You can use `fullStack` to combine stack traces of many errors:

```
var err1 = new VError('something bad happened');
var err2 = new VError(err1, 'something really bad happened here');

console.log(VError.fullStack(err2));
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about this package and it obviously looks interesting in this context. Still not sure how it would be better to apply it to this situation. I've tried to use `MultiError`, it outputs `first of 2 errors...`, which is nice, but stack traces are still lost when the error is logged.

Comment: I have edited my response with more details about `fullStack` method.

Comment: Thanks, it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Building upon https://stackoverflow.com/a/42147148/1703845, I abstracted the `VError.fullStack` call away like this

```
class FullStackVError extends VError {
  constructor(cause, ...args) {
    super(cause, ...args);

    let childFullStack;

    if (cause instanceof VError) {
      childFullStack = cause.stack;
      cause.stack = cause._originalStack;
    }

    this._originalStack = this.stack;
    this.stack = VError.fullStack(this);

    if (cause instanceof VError) {
      cause.stack = childFullStack;
    }
  }
}
```

Now `console.log(err2.stack);` is equivalent to what `console.log(VError.fullStack(err2));` would have been.